# Netty Threading Considerations

Tags: netty

We migrated from 3.x OIO to 4.x NIO due to a security vulnerability and have ran into lots of issues under heavy load.

Below are items we are addressing and curious if anyone disagrees or has other considerations when it comes to threading in Netty 4.x using NioEventLoopGroup.

- Offload message handling from occurring within handlers to free up the NioEventLoopGroup threads
- Offload operationComplete handling within listeners to free up NioEventLoopGroup threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that [the threading models used by Netty 4 and Netty 3 are *quite* different](https://livebook.manning.com/book/netty-in-action/chapter-7/31).

Comment: Thank You, I am buying this book now!